# Constructor with if returning wrong structure

Tags: data-structures, rust

I am creating simple generic structure representing edge in a graph, and I wanted constructor to switch arguments so the lower would be first.

```
pub type Index = u16;
pub type Cost = u32;

pub struct Edge<T> {
    first: Index,
    second: Index,
    weight: T,
}

impl<T> Edge<T> {
    pub fn new(first: Index, second: Index, weight: T) -> Self {
        return if second > first {
            Edge { second, first, weight }
        } else {
            Edge { first, second, weight }
        }
    }
}
```

However I am unable to make it work since my tests results in error.

```
 #[test]
    fn should_initialize_with_lover_value_first() {
        // given
        let lower: Index = 234;
        let high: Index = 444;
        let cost: Cost = 34;

        // when
        let edge: Edge<Cost> = Edge::new(high, lower, cost);

        // then
        assert_eq!(edge.first, lower, "edge.first = {}, expected = {}", edge.first, lower);
        assert_eq!(edge.second, high, "edge.second = {}, expected = {}", edge.second, high);
    }
```

I got error :

```
thread 'types::generic::edge::tests::should_initialize_with_lover_value_first' panicked at 'assertion failed: `(left == right)`
  left: `444`,
 right: `234`: edge.first = 444, expected = 234', src/types/generic/edge.rs:35:9
```

Am I missing some kind of werid rust behaviour that I am not aware of?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Rust lets you pun on the variable name when it's the same as the field name.](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch05-01-defining-structs.html#using-the-field-init-shorthand-when-variables-and-fields-have-the-same-name) So this:

```rust
Edge { second, first, weight }
```

is equivalent to this:

```rust
Edge {
    second: second,
    first: first,
    weight: weight,
}
```

And this:

```rust
Edge { first, second, weight }
```

is equivalent to this:

```rust
Edge {
    first: first,
    second: second,
    weight: weight,
}
```

As you can see, they both are equivalent to each other.

If you want to flip `first` and `second` then you can do this instead:

```rust
Edge {
    first: second,
    second: first,
    weight,
}
```

Comment: And that My friend is something that I was missing all along. Thank you !

Comment: @loganfsmyth just FYI, I'm reverting your edit since my original wording was intentional

Comment: @SamEstep Ok, maybe I'm just not following what you meant then. How does `pun` fit in that sentence? To me it seems grammatically very weird.

Comment: @loganfsmyth Here is another example: https://www.reddit.com/r/haskell/comments/buszoe/namedfieldpuns_what_does_pun_mean/ Specifically, I'm using the word "pun" as an intransitive verb: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/pun#Verb

Comment: Huh! Seems weird to use in a context without a joke/wordplay, and a very good way to confuse people, but fair enough. I immediately assumed it was a typo. TIL

Answer (score 1):

You might want to write it like this, since your code does not change the places where `first` and `second` are located:

```
pub fn new(first: Index, second: Index, weight: T) -> Self {
    return if second > first {
        Edge { first: second, second: first, weight }
    } else {
        Edge { first, second, weight }
    }
}
```